# Changing "return to shop" URL for all languages with WPML plugin

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, multilingual, wpml

In my WooCommerce Web shop I would like to change the "**Return to shop"** URL to a Custom URL. I tried to use the code below in the `function.php` file of my active theme, but it doesn't work.

On my website, I have five active languages managed by [**WPML**](https://wpml.org/) commercial plugin. It also runs a script which makes sure that visitors from these countries are redirected to their own language.

```
/**
 * Changes Return to Shop button URL on Cart page.
 *
 */

function wc_empty_cart_redirect_url() {
        return 'http://pacsymposium.com/';
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', 'wc_empty_cart_redirect_url' );
```

How can I make this working to get the current language shop link?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update2:** In your code, you need to use:

- WooCommerce [**`wc_get_page_id()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_page_id.html) function to get the WooCommerce shop page ID.
- WPML [**`wpml_object_id`**](https://wpml.org/wpml-hook/wpml_object_id/) filter hook to get the current language translated page ID for shop.
- WooCommerce [**`wc_get_page_permalink()`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_page_permalink.html) that is used by the filter hook itself (see [**HERE**](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect))

With that material, you can get the current translated link of the shop (or any other link).

So your code is going to be:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', 'wc_empty_cart_redirect_url' );
function wc_empty_cart_redirect_url() {

    // Getting the shop ID
    $shop_id = wc_get_page_id( 'shop' );

    // Getting the current language ID for the shop page
    $current_lang_id = apply_filters( 'wpml_object_id', $shop_id, 'page', TRUE );

    // Getting the post object for the ID
    $post = get_post($current_lang_id);

    // Getting the slug from this post object
    $slug = $post->post_name;

    // We re-use wc_get_page_permalink() function just like in this hook
    $link = wc_get_page_permalink( $slug );

    return  $link;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Finally I tested and it works…